# jquery remove part of string between [[ and ]]

Tags: jquery, string

Using Jquery I want to remove whatever is contained between square parenthesis eg:

[[to be removed]]

Ive tried a few things but can anyone help me out?

Thanks!

Comment: could you show us those `few things`? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't jQuery, just JavaScript.

```
"[[to be removed]]".replace(/\[{2}[^\]]+\]{2}/ig, "[[]]");
```

Comment: Cool thanks, but I should have mentioned the 'to be removed' text within the braces is variable - different each time

Comment: @MeltingDog the string "[[to be removed]]" is the string that the regex will look into, the magic is the regex pattern. It looks after two [[ and then any character except an ] followed by two ] and replace that match with [[]]

Comment: @MeltingDog you should consider accepting this answer by clicking the hollow "V" sign on the top left :) It motivates people to help you in the future

Answer (score 3):

Use the `replace` function:

```
yourStr.replace(/\[\[.*?\]\]/g,"[[]]");
```

Answer (score 2):

**Yet another a lil different demo** http://jsfiddle.net/amVS9/

**code**

```
$('div').text(function(_, text) {

   return text.replace(/\[\[.*?\]\]/g, "[[]]");
});
​
```

Answer (score 1):

You should look at the JavaScript replace() function.