# remove comment text from string in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have below text and remove comments text get rest of it.

```
var text ='<!-- FieldName="Title"
         FieldInternalName="Title"
         FieldType="SPFieldText"
      -->
        Test Project'
```

I just get `text="Test Project"`. How to do that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10944593/jquery-remove-part-of-string-between-and

Answer (score 1):

You can use built-in HTML parsing to do this. Append your text to an empty div, then use jQuery's [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) function to get the text in the `div`.

Here's a runnable snippet:

```js
var text ='<!-- FieldName="Title" FieldInternalName="Title" FieldType="SPFieldText" -->Test Project';
var newText = $("<div/>").append(text).text();
alert(newText);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just basic Regex. Here some documentation, and an example.

- [Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)
- [`String.prototype.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

http://jsbin.com/wezozejusu/1/edit?js,console

```
var text = '<!-- FieldName="Title" FieldInternalName="Title" FieldType="SPFieldText" --> Test Project';

var after = text.replace(/<!--(.*)-->[\s]*/g, '');
console.log(after);
```

Comment: It's best [not to try parsing HTML with RegEx](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/361762), especially when running in a browser, which can do the work for you.